# Can't access my form via $scope but can see it there

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope

I want to set my $error fields to $touched but I've notice I can't access `$scope.vm.InwardLeaseForm` even though I can see it when I console.log `$scope`.

Also `$scope.vm.InwardLeaseForm` and `vm.InwardLeaseForm` both return undefined.
This is my form

```
<div class="col-xs-12 btm40">
<h2 class="subHead">Lease Details</h2>
<div>
    <form name="vm.InwardLeaseForm" ng-submit="vm.saveInwardLeasingForm()" novalidate>
        <formly-form model="vm.InwardLeaseModel" fields="vm.InwardLeaseFields"
                     options="vm.InwardLeaseOptions" form="vm.InwardLeaseForm"></formly-form>
        <div class="top20">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-hide="vm.vehicleLockedFlag || vm.acquisitionCancelledFlag">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see it's present in `$scope`

[image]

Comment: Where are they initialised? Because it seems that InwardLeaseForm is a promise. I guess they don't have the value yet when you access them.

Comment: You're probably right. The form might be waiting for the data from web service to fill out the form with already stored data. Once the model is ready, vm.InwardLeaseForm becomes 'visible'.

Comment: can you explain why is there `vm`? Usually it's used in a _controllerAs_ syntax, where you can have `var vm = this;` (which makes it so that you don't need `$scope`). But it looks like you have `$scope.vm = {};` somewhere in there for some reason, which you then populate with other things

Comment: Correct. I'm using that approach. It works with vm.InwardLeaseForm flawlessly now. Eduardo was correct. No need for $scope but before the promise was returned it didn't work neither way.